# Cumulative number of Rows in DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am trying to count the cumulative number of rows in Power Pivot

I am using the formula below:

```
FilteredRows =
VAR LatestYear =
MAX ( Rates[Year] )
VAR UnfilteredTable =
ALL ( Rates )
RETURN
COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( UnfilteredTable, Rates[Year] <= LatestYear ) )
```

[image]

Instead of getting the sequence you see in FilteredRows I am get 11 (The total number of rows in all the rows)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FilteredRows =
COUNTROWS (
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Rates' ), 'Rates'[Year] <= MAX ( 'Rates'[Year] ) ),
        'Rates'[Year]
    )
)
```

When the years in `'Rates'[Year]` don't appear more than once, you don't need the SUMMARIZE function. In that case this will also work:

```
FilteredRows = COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( ALL ( 'Rates' ), Rates[Year] <= MAX ( Rates[Year] ) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you Marco for your help, I am using the 2nd formula since the year does not appear more than once, however it is still giving me the total number of rows rather than the cumulative number of rows

Comment: I have noticed something quite interesting, when i use your formula as a measure in a pivot table it works, when i use it as a column in power pivot it does not, quite interesting

Comment: This is normal DAX behaviour.  DAX-expressions are evaluated in a context (filter or row). The context in a matrix is different than the context in a table. That's why the result is different. This is an important topic to master if you want to learn DAX.

Comment: Since my answer seams to to work for you, could you please accept it as correct?

Comment: Sure no problem i did not do it just because i was building the model in power pivot and it does not work nevertheless you are right that it works on a pivot table. Any chance that you know what change to make to make it work on power pivot?

Comment: Try replacing the MAX function with the EARLIER function. Like this: `Column = COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL('Rates'),Rates[Year] <= EARLIER(Rates[Year])))`